# Trouble retrieving ID for waiting list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce am using a [waiting list plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/waitlist-woocommerce/) with a custom button and the only value I am missing is the product ID. But I am not able to locate it. Therefore when someone clicks on it I get an error. It's **undefined**.

```
 <a v-if="event.spaces_total - event.spaces_taken == 0" href="#" class="wcs-btn wcs-btn--action xoo-wl-btn button btn" :data-xoo_product_id="event.product_id" :data-min_qty="1" xwl-id="PRODUCT ID">Join Waitlist</a>
```

I contacted the developer and his suggestion was:

```
xwl-id="<?php global $product; echo $product->get_id(); ?>"
```

But this does not work... Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can try also: `xwl-id="<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>"`

Comment: thanks aztec, but that doesn't seem to work either the variables on debugger are still showing as undefined

Comment: sorry - https://wordpress.org/plugins/waitlist-woocommerce/

Comment: im using a custom button, that is being used inside an event calender plugin.

Comment: In this case I don't see how you can get the product ID, if it's not in a single product page, with the provided code and details of your question.